# Compare two set of objects

Tags: angularjs

I have scope called `$scope.users` which returns all the users in my app like so,

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Peter Boomsma"},
 {"id":2,"name":"Jan Jansen"},
 {"id":3,"name":"Kees Keesen"},
 {"id":4,"name":"Piet Pietersen"}]
```

Then I have a scope called `$scope.current_user` which returns the current users, and the id's of the users he's following,

```
{"id":4,"name":"Piet Pietersen","following":[
  {"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":4}]
}
```

I have a ng-repeat that shows all the users, and a `followUser` action per user,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)"} Follow user.
```

The problem is that I can't differentiate between a user that's already being followed, and a user that's not being followed. So the action `followUser` is always there. I would like to give the users the current user is following a different action, such as `unfollowUser`.

I got the id's of the users that the current user is following, but I don't know how to give those users a other button. Something like `unfollowUser`.

*** update ***

I've got it working (somewhat at least), by using Mihail his suggestion,

When I go to my user template I load the userCtrl,

```
usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
  $scope.users = response.data;

  angular.forEach(response, function(user){
    $scope.user = user

    $scope.isFollowed = function(userId) {
      var following = $scope.current_user.following;
      for (var i=0; i<following.length; i++) {
        if (following[i].id == userId) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  })
})
```

And in my template I have,

```
%ul{"ng-repeat" => "user in users"}
  %li
    name: {{ user.name }}
    %a{"ng-click" => "followUser(user)", "ng-show" => "!isFollowed(user.id)"} follow
    %a{"ng-click" => "unfollowUser(user)", "ng-show" => "isFollowed(user.id)"} unfollow
```

This works fine. When a user is followed then the unfollowUser function is used. The problem is that when I unfollow the user the view doesn't get updated. I have to refresh the page to see the effect of the unfollow action.

I've tried putting a `init` at the end of the unfollowUser action like so,

```
$scope.unfollowUser = function(user){
  unfollowFriend.unfollowFriend(user).then(function(){
  },function(){
  }).then(init);
  Notification.success(user.name + ' is verwijderd als vriend.');
}
```

The init,

```
var init = function(){
  console.log ('renew')
  usersService.loadUsers().then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;

    angular.forEach(response, function(user){
      $scope.user = user

      $scope.isFollowed = function(userId) {
        var following = $scope.current_user.following;
        for (var i=0; i<following.length; i++) {
          if (following[i].id == userId) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I get the `renew` message in my browser log, but the view isn't updated.

Comment: I upvoted MrRanos' answer. His concept is correct, but the implementation of this will matter as your user base and followers increase. You should change your `following` array to be an object storing the user id's as keys. You could store something in the value related to the user but it doesn't matter for the requirements so far that you posted. This will result in constant time execution of your algorithm as you look for a specific user id(key) rather than iterating through an eventually giant array of followers.

Comment: I agree with @Haymaker87 when you have a huge number of users this will not be a good solution. I suggest that in your init function after loading the users you can add an attribute for each user if he is followed or not. Then based on that attribute to do the checking. Also when you want to follow or unfollow a user you need to update the attribute so the view will be updated.

Comment: Thank you for your input. You say > update the attribute so the view will be updated but what attribute would that be? Because I'm using users to display the users, and when a user follows/unfollows that change is inside the relationship controller.

Comment: For example in you init function, you can check if a user is followed or not and based on that you can do something like `$scope.users[index].isFollowed = true/false`, and then when you click on the follow or unfollow button you do something like `$scope.users[index].isFollowed = !$scope.users[index].isFollowed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not good at haml, so I will write a simple html example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  <div ng-show="isFollowed(user.id)" ng-click="unfollowUser(user)">unfollow</div>
  <div ng-show="!isFollowed(user.id)" ng-click="followUser(user)">follow</div>
</div>


$scope.isFollowed = function(userId) {
  var following = $scope.current_user.following;
  for (var i=0; i<following.length; i++) {
    if (following[i].id == userId) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What is `userId` in this case?

Comment: You should iterate over all users in the list. Then in every cycle you will pass the id of the current iterated user to `isFollowed`. There you will validate if this id is in `$scope.current_user.following` - if true current user is following this user, if false not.

Comment: Alright. I've got it working, thanks for that. But I can't seem to get the view to change when a user is followed/unfollowed. I've updated my question to reflect the current code.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. It's that the scope users doesn't change if I follow or unfollow a other user.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that check if a given user is already followed like:

```
$scope.isFollowed = function (userID) {
  //check if the userID is in$scope.current_user.following
  //return a boolean
}
```

then in the HTML code you can check based on this function if to show followUser or unfollowUser.